# Fingering information for Romanian 5 hole Kaval/Caval in the Key of A

Tags: fingering, flute

I would like fingering information about the Romanian Kaval/Caval in the Key of A. It has five holes, a fipple and is played vertically.

The information I would like would be similar to whistle tabs, where the closed holes are shown as filled in circles, and the open holes are empty circles.

There would be a combination of filled and empty five circles for each note.

I am really struggling to find this information in English.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You shouldn't need a fingering chart: you just take off your fingers one by on which should give you A, B, C, D#, E, F. Then you can overblow for the same notes an octave higher. Then overblow more for notes a fifth higher: E, F#, G, A#, B, C

Comment: Not quite what you are looking for, but a piece with fingerings: https://musescore.com/user/30806280/scores/6633667 (scroll down for the 5-hole version)